# R object documentation: Package documentation as first item

Tags: r, documentation-generation, roxygen2

I have an R package and I want to display the general information about the package as first item in the created PDF manual.

I use `roxygen2` (version 7.0.2) for creating the documentation and followed the instructions given [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages).
When I create the documentation, the items appearing in the manual are all ordered alphabetically, including the item for the general documentation. But, of course, I want to have the general documentation at the top.

It seems that putting the package documentation item first must work somehow because it works in the [manual of knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/knitr.pdf).

My setup: I created a package "TestPackage" using RStudio, with one "hello.R" file:

```
#' Hello world function
#'
#' Prints "Hello, world!"
#'
#'@return nothing interesting
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

and one "TestPackage.R" file with the general documentation for the package.

```
#' A test package
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name TestPackage
NULL
```

When I run,

```
R CMD Rd2pdf TestPackage
```

I get a PDF manual with the first item "hello" and then the item "TestPackage".

How can I achive that the item for the package comes first?

Comment: Can you try changing the line `#' @name TestPackage` to `#' @name TestPackage-package`?

Comment: Madness! Thanks, this works! If you post it as an answer, I can accept it. Although this does the job, I also would appreciate some background info on why this works, if you can give some.

Comment: Those instructions you quote are a little old.  See here instead:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html#packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that the package documentation entry is first in the manual, you need its `name` to be `<packagename>-package` (where you replace `<packagename>` with the name of your package). Here you could accomplish that by changing

```
#' @name TestPackage
```

to

```
#' @name TestPackage-package
```

Why is this the case? Well, as always when you run into some strange corner of R package development, the best thing you can do is to consult the [Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). Here, we'd want to look at [Section 2.1, Rd format](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Rd-format) (the documentation files in R are in a format called `Rd`; `roxygen` creates the `Rd` files in `man/` for you). Specifically, in Section 2.1.1, we see

> \name{name}
>
> name typically<sup>101</sup> is the basename of the Rd file containing the documentation. ... Entries in the package manual will be in alphabetic<sup>102</sup> order of the \name entries.

That footnote 102 tells us

> in the current locale, and with special treatment for LaTeX special characters and with any ‘pkgname-package’ topic moved to the top of the list.

So, you have to `name` the `Rd` file as `pkgname-package` to move it to the top of the manual.

Comment: I think this happens automatically if you use the `_PACKAGE` sentinel described in the "Rd (documentation) tags" vignette in `roxygen2`.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on this? How can I use this "sentinel"?